# Bootstrap Jumbostron Background image disappear when open modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I'm using standart bootstrap "Jumbotron" template. I added background image to jumbotron:

```
.jumbotron{
    background: url("img/imgbg1.jpg") no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

When I open boostrap modal, jumbotron background image disappear and background is grey.

Why I have this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

Links to open modal use data-target attribute and remote location page

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="page.php" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-primary">Open me</a>
```

In this page, I loaded bootstrap css

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
```

that's why my jumbotron became grey!

I'm so stupid :-)